# Resize command prompt through commands

Tags: batch-file

I want to resize the command prompt window in a batch file, is it possible to set a height and width through something I can just add in the batch file?

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7941143/539542

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[Modify cmd.exe properties using the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945527/modify-cmd-exe-properties-using-the-command-prompt) Pretty much has what you're asking for. More on the topic, `mode con: cols=160 lines=78` should achieve what you want.
Change 160 and 78 to your values.

Comment: I am still confused as to what I would add to make command prompt open at a set height and width :s I shall try just adding what you said first.

Comment: Just type what i posted in the code tag: `mode con: cols=160 lines=78` makes the size change.

Comment: works, but you seem to lose the ability to scroll? Any way to keep that?

Comment: you can use this 2 lines to change width, height and enable scrolling: 1 line: 'mode con: cols=160 lines=78'; 2 line: 'powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=160;$B.height=9999;$W.buffersize=$B;}"'

Comment: I use this but it clears the previous text in the cmd window when put it midpoint down the code. It's like it does the `cls` command. It works at the top of the batch file though.

Comment: It simple opens a new window it doesn't change the window of the executed command!

Answer (score 18):

Simply type

```
MODE [width],[height]
```

Example:

```
MODE 14,1
```

That is the smallest size possible.

```
MODE 1000,1000
```

is the largest possible, although it probably won't even fit your screen.
If you want to minimize it, type

```
start /min [yourbatchfile/cmd]
```

and of course, to maximaze,

```
start /max [yourbatchfile/cmd]
```

I am currently working on doing this from the same batch files so that you don't have to have two or start it with cmd. of course, there are shortcuts, but I'm gonna try to figure it out.

Comment: will this resize the window or the buffer(e.g. will i be abl to scroll window's content?)

Comment: Yes. Simple is beautiful and smart! (In programming)

Comment: The MODE command doesn't work for me anymore after the latest update of Windows 11 (22H2 - Build 22621.755)

Answer (score 14):

```
mode con:cols=[whatever you want] lines=[whatever you want].
```

The unit is the number of characters that fit in the command prompt, eg.

```
mode con:cols=80 lines=100
```

will make the command prompt 80 ASCII chars of width and 100 of height

Comment: Yeah I was confused until I realized it resizes in ASCII Chars.

Answer (score 7):

Most people will tell you to run this command:

```
mode con:cols=80 lines=100
```

but you should just try typing:

```
MODE 1000
```

as a line in your batch file or cmd prompt.

Comment: But it changes only the width, not the height.

Comment: @Mai - You can specify both width and height: `mode 80,100`

Comment: could you expand on the difference?

Answer (score 5):

I know, that's a 8 years old question, but that can still happen today.

Powershell ca be used for that. An example is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-host?view=powershell-6).
The shortest command for the cmd is:

```
powershell -command "&{(get-host).ui.rawui.windowsize=@{width=100;height=55};}"
```

Set your wanted window size to the width and hight vars. However, this short line has two limitations:

- Be sure that the window size is not larger than the predefined buffer sizes. Otherwise there occur an error message.
- Depending on the system, loading and processing of Powershell takes 2...4 seconds. Sometimes this is a long time to wait.

To avoid that, in the command below the buffer size is defined. In addition, the process runs parallel to the other following cmd commands:

```
start /b powershell -command "&{$w=(get-host).ui.rawui;$w.buffersize=@{width=177;height=999};$w.windowsize=@{width=155;height=55};}"
```

The width and height values to the buffersize object, here 177 and 999, must be bigger or equal to the window size values.

Comment: With this command, you can keep the size of the buffer and only change the size of the window, i.e. when setting a small window, you have a scrollback buffer. With the `mode` command mentioned by others, you have no scrollback!
You can also attach commands to the powershell, e.g. `powershell -command "&{(get-host).ui.rawui.windowsize=@{width=100;height=55};}; cmd.exe /k"`(this was important for me).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/start /max [your batch]` it will fill the screen with the program it oppose to `/min`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a .bat file in full screen, right click on the "example.bat" and click create shortcut, then right click on the shortcut and click properties, then click layout, in layout you can adjust your file to the screen manually, however you can only run it this way if you use the shortcut. You can also change font size by clicking font instead of layout, select lucida and adjust the font size then click apply

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers given here can be used to temporarily change window size, they don't seem to affect font size (at least not on my PC). I have an alternative way. I don't know if this what you're looking for but if you want to make changes automatically/permanently to Console font/window size, you can always do a script that edits the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe
```

Those keys deal with the consoles that come up when your run a script or press shift and select "open command prompt here". The Command Prompt entry in your start menu does not use the registry to store it's preferences but stores the prefs in the shortcut itself.

I have a monitor that I can run in 720p native or 1440p supersampling. I needed a quick way to change my console's font/window size, so I made these scripts. These scripts do two things: (1) change the font/window sizes in the registry and (2) swap out the shortcuts in the Start menu with ones that have a different window and font size. I basically made two sets of copies of the Command Prompt and Power Shell shortcuts and stored them in Documents. One set of shortcuts was configured with Consolas font size at 16 for my monitor is in 720p (called it "Command Prompt.720pRes.lnk") and another version of the same shortcut was configure with font size at 36 (called it "Command Prompt.HighRes.lnk"). The script will copy from the set I want to use to overwrite the Start menu one.

**console-1440p.cmd:**

```
::Assign New Window and Font Size for Windows Command Prompt
set CMDpNewFont=00240000
set CMDpNewWindowSize=000f0078
set commandPromptLinkFlag=highRes



 ::Make temporary .reg file to resize command console

>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO.
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "WindowSize"=dword:%CMDpNewWindowSize%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "FontSize"=dword:%CMDpNewFont%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO.
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe]
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "WindowSize"=dword:%CMDpNewWindowSize%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "FontSize"=dword:%CMDpNewFont%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO.
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "WindowSize"=dword:%CMDpNewWindowSize%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "FontSize"=dword:%CMDpNewFont%


::Merge and delete consoleSIZEchanger.reg
REGEDIT /S %temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg 
del %temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg 

::Copy Preconfigured Command Prompt/PowerShell shortcuts to Pinned Start Menu, Accessories and any other Custom Location you would define
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Command Prompt.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Command Prompt.lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Command Prompt.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Command Prompt.lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Windows PowerShell.lnk"                 
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell (x86).%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell (x86).lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell (x86).%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Windows PowerShell (x86).lnk"
```

**console-720p.cmd:**

```
::Assign New Window and Font Size for Windows Command Prompt
set CMDpNewFont=00100000
set CMDpNewWindowSize=0014007d
set commandPromptLinkFlag=720Res



 ::Make temporary .reg file to resize command console
>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO.
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "WindowSize"=dword:%CMDpNewWindowSize%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "FontSize"=dword:%CMDpNewFont%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO.
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe]
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "WindowSize"=dword:%CMDpNewWindowSize%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "FontSize"=dword:%CMDpNewFont%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO.
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "WindowSize"=dword:%CMDpNewWindowSize%
>>%temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg ECHO "FontSize"=dword:%CMDpNewFont%


::Merge and delete consoleSIZEchanger.reg
REGEDIT /S %temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg 
del %temp%\consoleSIZEchanger.reg 

::Copy Preconfigured Command Prompt/PowerShell shortcuts to Pinned Start Menu, Accessories and any other Custom Location you would define
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Command Prompt.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Command Prompt.lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Command Prompt.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Command Prompt.lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell.%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Windows PowerShell.lnk"                 
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell (x86).%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell (x86).lnk"
copy "%homedrive%%homepath%\Documents\Windows PowerShell (x86).%commandPromptLinkFlag%.lnk" "%homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Windows PowerShell (x86).lnk"
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there's a much simpler way to do this. If you just open the batch file, click on the window, and then click "properties", and then to "layout", and scroll down to "Window Size", you can edit it from there. It will also stay that way every time you open that specific batch file, so it's pretty handy.

Comment: The question is "I want to resize the command prompt window in a batch file"