# Enable programmatically the "Quick Edit Mode" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

Does anyone know how to enable or disable programmatically the "Quick Edit Mode" in PowerShell or CMD console ?
I would like to lauch PowerShell from a script (batch) and to give the same look and behavior as the default PowerShell console lauched from the shortcut.

Comment: See an easy solution on bellow Stack OverFlow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872345/script-commands-to-disable-quick-edit-mode

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855923/15016163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set/create a QuickEdit DWord value with value of 1 under the following regkey:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\<look for powershell related key>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anybody still looking for a solution, this will disable Quick Edit in the current PowerShell window (tested for windows 10):

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int mode);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);
"@ -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods
$Handle = [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetStdHandle(-10)
return [Win32.NativeMethods]::SetConsoleMode($Handle, 0x0080)
```

Per [this script](https://gist.github.com/9999years/29cc23640cef8e9130bbe3501078b510) the first call gets the current STDIN, and per [this script](https://gist.github.com/sthonnard/31106e47eab8d6f3329ef530717e8079?permalink_comment_id=4035236) the second call invokes the SetConsoleMode API with the right value.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7941598/3000416), update "QuickMode" setting in Windows Registry:

```sh
reg add HKCU\Console /v QuickEdit /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

However it will not affect currently opened window. But you can reopen a window:

```sh
:: Get QuickEdit Mode setting from Windows Registry
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Console" /v QuickEdit`) DO (
  set quickEditSetting=%%A %%B
)

if %quickEditSetting% == 0x0 (
  :: Disable QuickEdit Mode
  reg add HKCU\Console /v QuickEdit /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

  :: Open script in a new Command Prompt window
  start "" "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
)

... script logic here ...
exit
```

Additional info about `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` Registry configuration - https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/console/index