# Script commands to disable quick edit mode

Tags: powershell

does anyone know how to disable quick edit mode from within a powershell script?  This question's "answer" is not an answer:

[Enable programmatically the "Quick Edit Mode" in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929106/enable-programmatically-the-quick-edit-mode-in-powershell)

(Though one could set the registry setting programatically, doing so would not affect the current session).

I have looked at the `$host`, `$host.UI` and `$host.UI.RawUI` objects and cannot find anything relevant.

To make things a bit more clear, I do not want to change the registry.  In particular, I do not want to change the default behaviour.  In fact, there is just one script, and really only one branch of the script, where I need to disable quick-edit.  So I need to be able to disable it programatically.  Or at the very least, be able to start powershell with command line options to disable quick edit.

Thanks.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Can you give me a bit more information?  How do you know this?  For example, is this simply because the relevant object properties have not been exposed, or is it a fundamental issue with how IO is done in a shell window?  Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge `$host.UI.RawUI` is the only way to change console properties on the fly from within PowerShell. And that object simply doesn't provide a property or method to enable/disable QuickEdit.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855923/15016163

Comment: @MaiconMaurico Thanks Maicon. [Comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872345/script-commands-to-disable-quick-edit-mode?noredirect=1#comment135505082_30872345) gives Python code equavalent to the c# code in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42792718/1082063). Given that c# code can be complied dynamically in PowerShell, this also provides Powershell functionality.

Answer (score 6):

I hope not too late.

This solution based on C#, but it does not use any global settings or registry.

Solution based on  this Stack Overflow question:
[How to programmatic disable C# Console Application's Quick Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656846/how-to-programmatic-disable-c-sharp-console-applications-quick-edit-mode)

```
$QuickEditCodeSnippet=@" 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 
public static class DisableConsoleQuickEdit
{
 
const uint ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT = 0x0040;

// STD_INPUT_HANDLE (DWORD): -10 is the standard input device.
const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

public static bool SetQuickEdit(bool SetEnabled)
{

    IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    // get current console mode
    uint consoleMode;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
    {
        // ERROR: Unable to get console mode.
        return false;
    }

    // Clear the quick edit bit in the mode flags
    if (SetEnabled)
    {
        consoleMode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;
    }
    else
    {
        consoleMode |= ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT;
    }

    // set the new mode
    if (!SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode))
    {
        // ERROR: Unable to set console mode
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}

"@

$QuickEditMode=add-type -TypeDefinition $QuickEditCodeSnippet -Language CSharp


function Set-QuickEdit() 
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="This switch will disable Console QuickEdit option")]
    [switch]$DisableQuickEdit=$false
)


    if([DisableConsoleQuickEdit]::SetQuickEdit($DisableQuickEdit))
    {
        Write-Output "QuickEdit settings has been updated."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Something went wrong."
    }
}
```

Now you can disable or enable Quick Edit option by:

```
Set-QuickEdit -DisableQuickEdit
Set-QuickEdit
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Yes, it's too late - I'm long past the problem.  But if I have time to test this out, I will do that and mark as answer.  Looks very promising.  OTOH, perhaps you could comment on the relevance of AveYo's comment below?

Comment: I had the same problem and your answer worked well for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

David,

I’m not sure if you’ve found the solution to your problem or not, but I came across your post while researching a way to have a PowerShell scrip disable the Quick Edit option under the Edit Options. As far as I know from my research, Rahul is correct: the only way to make this change ‘programmatically’ is through the registry. I know you said that you don’t want to change the registry, but there is a way to change the registry value, start a new powershell process, execute a script block in that powershell process, then change the registry value back. This is how you would do it:

Assuming the necessary registry value does not exist:

```
Set-Location HKCU:\Console
New-Item ‘.%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_Powershell.exe’
Set-Location ‘.%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_Powershell.exe’
New-ItemProperty . QuickEdit –Type DWORD –Value 0x00000000
Start-Process Powershell.exe “&{ <#The scrip block you want to run with Quick Edit disabled#> }”
Set-ItemProperty . QuickEdit –Value 0x00000001
Pop-Location
```

Assuming the necessary registry value does exist:

```
Set-Location HKCU:\Console
Set-Location ‘.%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_Powershell.exe’
Set-ItemProperty . QuickEdit –Value 0x00000000
Start-Process Powershell.exe “&{ <#The scrip block you want to run with Quick Edit disabled#> }”
Set-ItemProperty . QuickEdit –Value 0x00000001
Pop-Location
```

If you insert this code into the portion of your script that you want to run with Quick Edit disabled, you should get the result you’re looking for. Hopefully this helps.

-Cliff

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, that will work, but there are other, simpler ways to solve the real problem I have.  Disabling quick-edit would have solved my problem it it could be done simply, but since it can't be done simply, I can resort to other methods of solving my real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Krisz's answer i made an improved version to support both of **Quick edit mode** and **Insert mode**

```
$QuickEditCodeSnippet=@" 
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class ConsoleModeSettings
{
    const uint ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT = 0x0040;
    const uint ENABLE_INSERT_MODE = 0x0020;

    const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

    public static void EnableQuickEditMode()
    {
        SetConsoleFlag(ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT, true);
    }

    public static void DisableQuickEditMode()
    {
        SetConsoleFlag(ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT, false);
    }

    public static void EnableInsertMode()
    {
        SetConsoleFlag(ENABLE_INSERT_MODE, true);
    }

    public static void DisableInsertMode()
    {
        SetConsoleFlag(ENABLE_INSERT_MODE, false);
    }

    private static void SetConsoleFlag(uint modeFlag, bool enable)
    {
        IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        uint consoleMode;
        if (GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
        {
            if (enable)
                consoleMode |= modeFlag;
            else
                consoleMode &= ~modeFlag;
            
            SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode);
        }
    }
}

"@ 

$QuickEditMode=add-type -TypeDefinition $QuickEditCodeSnippet -Language CSharp

function Set-ConsoleProperties() 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$EnableQuickEditMode=$false,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$DisableQuickEditMode=$false,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$EnableInsertMode=$false,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$DisableInsertMode=$false
    )

    if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0)
    {
        [ConsoleModeSettings]::EnableQuickEditMode()
        [ConsoleModeSettings]::EnableInsertMode()
        Write-Output "All settings have been enabled"
        return
    }

    if ($EnableQuickEditMode)
    {
        [ConsoleModeSettings]::EnableQuickEditMode()
        Write-Output "QuickEditMode has been enabled"
    }

    if ($DisableQuickEditMode)
    {
        [ConsoleModeSettings]::DisableQuickEditMode()
        Write-Output "QuickEditMode has been disabled"
    }

    if ($EnableInsertMode)
    {
        [ConsoleModeSettings]::EnableInsertMode()
        Write-Output "InsertMode has been enabled"
    }

    if ($DisableInsertMode)
    {
        [ConsoleModeSettings]::DisableInsertMode()
        Write-Output "InsertMode has been disabled"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Set-ConsoleProperties -EnableQuickEditMode -DisableInsertMode
Set-ConsoleProperties -DisableQuickEditMode -DisableInsertMode
Set-ConsoleProperties
```

Comment: @Krisz and a0s : very nice. Thanks to both of you for such quality answers. When I can run these and verify, I will likely select Krisz answer as the answer, just because his was the first.  But a0s, yours is great. Thanks.

Comment: Suggested change/edit (paraphrased to fit in comment): `if($enable) { if($disable) { Write-Output "error msg" } else {...enable} } elseif($disable} { ...disable }` - I don't like allowing the user to specify both enable and disable: which should take precedence?

Answer (score 0):

Krisz' and Clifford's answers didn't work for me. I had a powershell script that I wanted to run (a long-running script that should NOT be interrupted by mouse clicks). In my example, I use `DoWork.ps1` to be that long-running script.

I created a batch file to set the reg-key values:

**RunScript.bat**

```
@echo off
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%DoWork.ps1

: Disable QuickEdit
PowerShell -Command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Console' -Name 'QuickEdit' -Value 0x00000000" 
PowerShell -Command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_Powershell.exe' -Name 'QuickEdit' -Value 0x00000000" 

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}"

: Re-enable QuickEdit 
PowerShell -Command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Console' -Name 'QuickEdit' -Value 0x00000001" 
PowerShell -Command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_Powershell.exe' -Name 'QuickEdit' -Value 0x00000001"
```

**DoWork.ps1**

```
$i = 0
while ($i -lt 1000)
{
    Write-Output "i:$i"
    $i++
    sleep(1)
}
```

Put RunScript.bat and DoWork.ps1 in the same folder and double click/invoke RunScript.bat to kick off DoWork.ps1. Notice that the QuickEdit checkbox in the Powershell "Properties" setting is disabled.

Setting `HKCU:\Console\QuickEdit` to 0 disables QuickEdit "Default" setting only for the **Command Prompt** and setting `HKCU:\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe\QuickEdit` to 0 disables QuickEdit "Properties" setting for the Powershell window that is invoked by the RunScript.bat file.

AFAIK, I don't think QuickEdit "Default" setting affects anything. But what seems to be important is that:

1. `HKCU:\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe\QuickEdit` must be set to 0.
2. The powershell script you wish to run MUST be invoked from a batch file. Even if you have both registry keys set to 0, the QuickEdit "Properties" checkbox will still checked (enabled).